# Cocos2d: Is it ok to have a pointer to a parent's class pointer?

Tags: pointers, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

Silly question. Cocos2d is build around the parent-child hierarchy. I was wondering if it is ok to have a parent class (e.g. GameScene) and initialize a child class (e.g. SpriteHandler) with a pointer to a member of the parent class (e.g. CCSpriteBatchNode*).

I am trying to do this to optimize the number of CCSpriteBatchNodes. Here is a code snippet of my main class (GameScene style).

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

enum ShooterSceneLayerTags {
    HudLayerTag = 0,
    };

@interface ShooterScene : CCLayer {
    CCSpriteBatchNode* sharedSpriteBatchNode;
}


-(id) initWithSharedBatchNodeReference:( CCSpriteBatchNode*) sharedSpriteBatchNode;
+ (id) sceneWithId:(int)sceneId;
 @end


#import "ShooterScene.h"
#import "MainMenuScene.h"

//Layers
#import "LevelSpritesLayer.h"
#import "HudLayer.h"



@interface ShooterScene (PrivateMethods)
-(void) addLayers:(int)sceneId;
-(void) loadGameArtFile;
-(BOOL) verifyAndHandlePause;
@end

@implementation ShooterScene

+ (id) sceneWithId:(int)sceneId
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    ShooterScene * shooterLayer = [[self alloc] initWithId:sceneId];
    [scene addChild:shooterLayer];

    return scene;    
}

-(id) initWithId:(int)sceneId 
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        //Load game art before adding layers - This will initialize the batch node
        [self loadGameArtFile:sceneId]; 

        //Will add sprites to shared batch node for performance
        [self addLayers:sceneId];
        [self addChild:sharedSpriteBatchNode];

        //Do other stuff..
        [self scheduleUpdate];

    }
    return self;

}

-(void) addLayers:(int)sceneId
{
    LevelSpritesLayer * levelData = [LevelSpritesLayer node];
    [levelData initWithSharedBatchNodeReference:sharedSpriteBatchNode];

    [self addChild:levelData];

    switch (sceneId) {
        case 1:
            [levelData loadLevelOneSprites];
            break;
        case 2:
            [levelData loadLevelTwoSprites];
            break;            
        default:
            break;
    }

    HudLayer * hud = [HudLayer node];
    [hud setUpPauseMenu];
    [self addChild:hud z:1 tag:HudLayerTag];
}

-(BOOL) verifyAndHandlePause
{
    HudLayer * hud = [self getChildByTag:HudLayerTag];
    if(hud.pauseRequested){
         [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[MainMenuScene scene]];

        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    if([self verifyAndHandlePause]==false)
    {
        //Continue with animation etc.. 


    }
}

/**
 This is tricky. Could have loaded this in LevelData but as I am expecting to use the same SpriteSheet for HudLayer as well then 
 I prefer to have the control here of this. Also, the same sheet could be used for more level, hence specific function is not bad 
 **/
-(void) loadGameArtFile:(int) sceneId
{
    CCSpriteFrameCache* frameCache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];
    [frameCache addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"game-art-hd.plist"];

    sharedSpriteBatchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"game-art-hd.png"];
}

//As dealloc is deprecated, I prefer to remove unused sprites and texture on cleanup
-(void) cleanup
{
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames];     
}
```

**And here is one of the loadLevelData methods, it uses the sharedSpriteBAtchNodeReference**

```
-(void) loadLevelOneSprites
{
    //Just a proof of concept example
    testSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"File0.png"];
    testSprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
    testSprite.position = CGPointMake(160.0f, 240.0f);
    [sharedSpriteBatchNodeReference addChild:testSprite];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What [Ben] said. It should not be a retaining or strong reference, the latter being the default in ARC for instance variables.

There is one way to ensure under ARC that you're retain-cycle-safe even if you use a strong reference. Override the cleanup method and nil the reference there (under MRC you should also call release here, if you retained the reference):

```
-(void) cleanup
{
    sharedSpriteBatchNode = nil;
    [super cleanup];
}
```

Doing this in dealloc won't work. As long as a child node has a strong reference to a parent, it will not be deallocated. So you need to do this in cleanup, and ensure that all method calls where you can set the cleanup flag has that parameter set to YES.

But there are other, and I think better, solutions than passing a parent node in the initializer. For example you could get the shared batch node via a common tag from the parent, and either do that every time you need it (wrap it into a small function) or store it in a weak (non-retaining) instance var:

```
// onEnter is typically called right after init (during addChild)
// parent is already set here
-(void) onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];

    CCSpriteBatchNode* sharedBatchNode = [parent getChildByTag:kSharedBatchNodeTag];
}
```

Or get the parent and cast it, assuming the sharedBatchNode to be a property of the parent class:

```
-(void) whereEver
{
    ShooterScene* scene = (ShooterScene*)parent;
    CCSpriteBatchNode* sharedBatchNode = scene.sharedSpriteBatchNode;
    …

    // you can also reduce the above to a single line:
    CCSpriteBatchNode* batch = ((ShooterScene*)parent).sharedSpriteBatchNode;
}
```

**Especially this latter solution is recommended.** Even if you need to do that often it's fast. Casting is free, property access no more than a message send. Just be sure that the parent is in fact an object of the class you're casting it to.

Comment: Thank you Steffen, nice and clear answer. Rich of ideas I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that but if you are using ARC you should make your sharedSpriteBatchNode a weak pointer. If you don't you could end up with a **circular reference**.

What will happen with the circular reference is when the Director releases your game scene after it has finished running  your game scene will still have your child retaining it and your game scene will still be retaining that child. This circle will float off and never be able to be released as it is abandoned.

Comment: Thanks Ben, interesting answer. I will consider this in the future. I upvoted it but accepted LearnCocos2D one as it offered an "innovative" solution for my problem but to be fair your answer should be accepted as well and both should be considered.

Comment: You should always accept the answer that is most helpful. I agree, Steffen's answer is better than mine and he deserves it!

Comment: I am so appreciative of being able to ask things to a such wide and helpful community like in SO. Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I hope, once I will have published my first game, to know enough to help back as much as you guys do :).